# Soundboard app: Play sound as long as the user is pressing the button

Tags: xcode, touch, avaudioplayer

I am making a soundboard app and i am using sounds with over 30sec duration. I am playing the sound by connecting in IB my action with a "touch down" event, however the sound keeps playing once started. I connected in the some button a "touch cancel" & "touch up outside" event that is supposed to stop the sound but for some reason it doesn't. 
Can anybody provide a solution to my problem?

---Edit---
Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {
     NSString *soundFile;
    soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testSound" ofType:@"mp3"];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile] error:nil];
    audioPlayer.volume = volumeSlider.value;
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];
}

-(IBAction)stopSound:(id)sender {
    [audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Touch up outside" refers to when the button is pressed down and the user's finger moves and lifts outside of the control.

It sounds like you're looking for the "**Touch up inside**" event.

However, just to be sure, you should post the code you're using to start and stop the sound.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was on pressing a button down (the evernt that performs my action), I hooked the action 1.) Touch Down 2.) Touch Drag Enter

To turn the button off (cancel the action) I added to the button - 1.) Touch Up Inside 2.) Touch Up Outside 3.) Touch Cancel 4.) Touch Drag Exit